# tkinter and matplotlib canvas shows, but not navigation toolbar and graph title

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, title

I am creating a program that incorportes matplotlib into tkinter. The majority of the program works including displaying the canvas of the graph, however, the graph title,navigation toolbar and the xy legends do not show. The part of the code I am wondering about is right at the bottom of the script:

```
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg( canvas, root ) 
toolbar.update() 
canvas._tkcanvas.grid(row=9,column=0)
plt.xlabel('x label')
plt.ylabel('y label')
plt.title('Graph')
plt.show()
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? Any help would be extremely appreciated!

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as Tk
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
import sys


root = Tk.Tk()

#Interface-----------------------------------------------------------

title_label = Button(root,text = "Add graph title", padx=2,pady=2)
xlabel = Button(root,text =      "Add X values    ", padx=2,pady=2)
ylabel = Button(root,text =      "Add Y values    ", padx=2,pady=2)
nameXaxis = Button(root,text =   "Name X axis      ", padx=2,pady=2)
nameYaxis = Button(root,text =   "Name Y axis      ", padx=2,pady=2)
meanLabel = Button(root,text = "Mean          ")
stderrorLabel = Button(root,text = "StdError:     ")

barGraph = Button(root,text = "Bar Graph  ",fg = "red", padx=2,pady=2)
lineGraph = Button(root,text = "Line Graph", fg = "red",padx=2,pady=2)
pieGraph = Button(root,text = "Pie Graph  ",fg = "red",padx=2,pady=2)

titleEntry = Entry(root)
xentry = Entry(root)
yentry = Entry(root)
nameXaxisEntry = Entry(root)
nameYaxisEntry = Entry(root)
meanText = Text(root,height=1,width=4)
stderrText = Text(root,height=1,width=4)        


title_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0,sticky = E)
xlabel.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = E)
ylabel.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = E)
nameXaxis.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = E)
nameYaxis.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = E)

barGraph.grid(row = 0,column = 1,ipadx=10,sticky=W)
lineGraph.grid(row = 1,column = 1,ipadx=10,sticky=W)
pieGraph.grid(row = 2,column = 1,ipadx=10,sticky=W)

meanLabel.grid(row = 3,column = 1,ipadx=10,sticky=W)
stderrorLabel.grid(row = 4,column = 1,ipadx=10,sticky=W)                      


titleEntry.grid(row = 0, column = 0,ipadx=100,sticky=W)
xentry.grid(row = 1, column = 0,ipadx=100,sticky=W)
yentry.grid(row = 2, column = 0,ipadx=100,sticky=W)
nameXaxisEntry.grid(row = 3, column = 0,ipadx=100,sticky=W)
nameYaxisEntry.grid(row = 4, column = 0,ipadx=100,sticky=W)
meanText.grid(row=3,column=3,sticky=W)
stderrText.grid(row=4,column=3,sticky=W)

# Adding line graph to Canvas--------------------------------------------


root.title("Naynts Graphs") 

fig = Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100) 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111) 

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,root) 
canvas.show() 
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=7,column=0) 

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg( canvas, root ) 
toolbar.update() 
canvas._tkcanvas.grid(row=9,column=0)

# Adding features to graph

plt.xlabel('x label')
plt.ylabel('y label')
plt.title('Graph')
plt.show()


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer might come a little late, but I stumbled upon this problem recently as well and here's what you can do:

For your problem with the toolbar I can refer to this question:
[Displaying Matplotlib Navigation Toolbar in Tkinter via grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913854/displaying-matplotlib-navigation-toolbar-in-tkinter-via-grid?rq=1).

NavigationToolbar calls .pack() internally and pack() and grid() dont't work together. But you can create a Tk.Frame on your root frame and pack the toolbar in there:

```
toolbar_frame = Tk.Frame(root)
toolbar_frame.grid(row=9,column=0)
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, toolbar_frame) 
toolbar.update()
```

If you want to display axis label call plt.figure instead of Figure. This worked in my case:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100)
```

The way you wrote the code didn't work on my setup, so I made some other changes. The results looks the following:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
#from matplotlib.figure import Figure
#from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as Tk
#import numpy as np
#import math
#import matplotlib
#matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
#from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
#import sys


root = Tk.Tk()

#Interface-----------------------------------------------------------

title_label = Tk.Button(root,text = "Add graph title", padx=2,pady=2)
xlabel = Tk.Button(root,text =      "Add X values    ", padx=2,pady=2)
ylabel = Tk.Button(root,text =      "Add Y values    ", padx=2,pady=2)
nameXaxis = Tk.Button(root,text =   "Name X axis      ", padx=2,pady=2)
nameYaxis = Tk.Button(root,text =   "Name Y axis      ", padx=2,pady=2)
meanLabel = Tk.Button(root,text = "Mean          ")
stderrorLabel = Tk.Button(root,text = "StdError:     ")

barGraph = Tk.Button(root,text = "Bar Graph  ",fg = "red", padx=2,pady=2)
lineGraph = Tk.Button(root,text = "Line Graph", fg = "red",padx=2,pady=2)
pieGraph = Tk.Button(root,text = "Pie Graph  ",fg = "red",padx=2,pady=2)

titleEntry = Tk.Entry(root)
xentry = Tk.Entry(root)
yentry = Tk.Entry(root)
nameXaxisEntry = Tk.Entry(root)
nameYaxisEntry = Tk.Entry(root)
meanText = Tk.Text(root,height=1,width=4)
stderrText = Tk.Text(root,height=1,width=4)        


title_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0,sticky = Tk.E)
xlabel.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = Tk.E)
ylabel.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = Tk.E)
nameXaxis.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = Tk.E)
nameYaxis.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = Tk.E)

barGraph.grid(row = 0,column = 1,ipadx=10,sticky=Tk.W)
lineGraph.grid(row = 1,column = 1,ipadx=10,sticky=Tk.W)
pieGraph.grid(row = 2,column = 1,ipadx=10,sticky=Tk.W)

meanLabel.grid(row = 3,column = 1,ipadx=10,sticky=Tk.W)
stderrorLabel.grid(row = 4,column = 1,ipadx=10,sticky=Tk.W)                      


titleEntry.grid(row = 0, column = 0,ipadx=100,sticky=Tk.W)
xentry.grid(row = 1, column = 0,ipadx=100,sticky=Tk.W)
yentry.grid(row = 2, column = 0,ipadx=100,sticky=Tk.W)
nameXaxisEntry.grid(row = 3, column = 0,ipadx=100,sticky=Tk.W)
nameYaxisEntry.grid(row = 4, column = 0,ipadx=100,sticky=Tk.W)
meanText.grid(row=3,column=3,sticky=Tk.W)
stderrText.grid(row=4,column=3,sticky=Tk.W)

# Adding line graph to Canvas--------------------------------------------


root.title("Naynts Graphs") 

#fig = Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100) 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111) 

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,root) 
canvas.show() 
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=7,column=0) 

toolbar_frame = Tk.Frame(root)
toolbar_frame.grid(row=9,column=0)
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, toolbar_frame) 
toolbar.update() 
#canvas._tkcanvas.grid(row=9,column=0)

# Adding features to graph

plt.xlabel('x label')
plt.ylabel('y label')
plt.title('Graph')
plt.show()

#root.mainloop()
Tk.mainloop()
```

I think you use many unnecessary imports, that may conflict with each other, which was the case for me with 
`from Tkinter import *` and `import Tkinter as Tk`. Hope this helps!